# Why browsers ignores /etc/hosts behind a SOCKS proxy?

Tags: macos, network, proxy, socks

My MacBook in office does not have internet access. So I set up an instant SOCKS Proxy over SSH to surf the web.

However, when I try to add an entry to `/etc/hosts`, the browser does not go to the site I expected ...

My MacBook's WIFI is off and is connected to the company LAN:

```
 IP address:  192.168.8.250
 Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
 Router:      192.168.8.1
 DNS server:  8.8.8.8
```

Be default, there is not internet access.

There a Linux development box (192.168.12.128) which has access to the internet, so I set up an instant SOCKS proxy to gain internet access for my MacBook:

```
 ssh -fND localhost:30000 ohho@192.168.12.128
```

Then in my MacBook's System Preferences > Network > Proxies

```
 (Enable) SOCKS Proxy
 SOCKS Proxy sever: 127.0.0.1:30000
 Bypass proxy settings for these Hosts & Domains:
   *.local, 169.254/16, 127.0.0.1
```

Now I can surf the web, so far so good.

For development, I set up a few entries in `/etc/hosts` for virtual hosts purpose:

```
 127.0.0.1 air.company.com
```

In `bash`:

```
 $ ping air.company.com
 PING air.ohho.es (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.046 ms

 $ curl air.company.com
 <html>OK</html>
```

It looks good and `curl` returns the content of the `index.html` nicely.

However, if I try to open the site:`http://air.company.com` in the browsers (Safari/Chrome/Firefox), none of them returns the result like `curl` did. Chrome give an error:

> This webpage is not available The webpage at http://air.company.com/
>   might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new
>   web address. Error 120 (net::ERR_SOCKS_CONNECTION_FAILED): Unknown
>   error.

If I add another entry in `/etc/hosts`:

```
 127.0.0.1 www.microsoft.com
```

In `bash`:

```
 $ ping www.microsoft.com
 PING www.microsoft.com (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.047 ms
 64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.128 ms
 ^C
 --- www.microsoft.com ping statistics ---
 2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
 round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.047/0.087/0.128/0.041 ms

 $ curl www.microsoft.com
 <html>OK</html>
```

However, the browsers returns the content from the web server of the real Microsoft site, instead of the content from my MacBook (127.0.01). Why?

p.s.

If I disable the SOCKS proxy, the browser returns the content from 127.0.0.1 correctly.

If I disconnect the LAN cable, the browser returns the content from 127.0.0.1 correctly.

Comment: The information security officer in me needs to ask, Is there a reason your office doesn't provide public internet access, Mr. Snowden? ;)

Comment: What if you don't put 127.0.0.1 in the bypass? Is is still localhost and shouldn't use the proxy anyway. Maybe it's the bypass function tripping up the browsers.

Comment: It's just stupid of Microsoft that the file only gets used without a proxy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your browser is asking the SOCKS proxy for the sites, it is not connecting directly. Therefore putting the IP address in the exceptions list doesn't work, as your computer is not performing the look up of air.company.com to 127.0.0.1. The SOCKS proxy is.

To avoid this, place the full domain name of what you are accessing locally in the exceptions list in System Preferences > Network > Proxies.

So for air.company.com you'd see an exception list (from your example above) of:

```
  *.local, 169.254/16, 127.0.0.1, air.company.com
```

Your computer will now connect to air.company.com directly, and therefore make use of /etc/hosts.

Comment: It's just stupid of Microsoft that the file only gets used without a proxy.